# Unable to open graph with TitanFactory - MemoryMeter error

Tags: cassandra, jvm, titan, gremlin

I am trying to create a graph using the `titan-cassandra-embedded-es.properties` file. This is failing miserably. The steps I am doing:

```
iulian@iulian-ThinkPad-T530:~/titan$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----
10:32:58 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-embedded-es.properties')
10:33:22 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor  - Unable to initialize MemoryMeter (jamm not specified as javaagent).  This means Cassandra will be unable to measure object sizes accurately and may consequently OOM.
10:33:22 WARN  org.apache.cassandra.utils.CLibrary  - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
10:33:23 ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable  - MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.   Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE;  upgrade to the Sun JRE instead
==>titangraph[embeddedcassandra:[127.0.0.1]]
```

The properties of the `titan-cassandra-embedded-es.properties` file are as follows:

```
storage.backend=embeddedcassandra
storage.conf-file=cassandra.yaml
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 0
cache.db-cache-time = 0
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.directory=../db/es
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=false
index.search.elasticsearch.local-mode=true
```

I should add I have both Oracle JDK 8 and Open-JDK on the machine. But everything should be pointing to the Oracle JVM.

```
JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_40

iulian@iulian-ThinkPad-T530:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

This tip might help:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Titan-Limitations#removing-jamm-warning-messages

It basically says that the solution is to add this `JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable:

```
export JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:$TITAN_HOME/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```